# If $\{b_{n}\}$ is obtained by deleting the first $k$ members of $\{a_{n}\}$, then $\{b_{n}\}$ is convergent iff $\{a_{n}\}$ is convergent.

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence

The question says:

Let $k  \in N$. If the sequence $\{b_{n}\}$ is obtained by deleting the first $k$ members of the sequence $\{a_{n}\}$, then $\{b_{n}\}$ is convergent iff $\{a_{n}\}$ is convergent.

Could anyone give me a hint please?

Comment: $\{a_n\} $ converges to $A$ ifff, for every $r>0$, the set $\{n: a_n\not\in [-r+A,r+A]\}$ is finite.

Comment: @DanielWainfleet okay then what is the next step?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The sequence $\{b_n\}$ is obtained from $\{a_n\}$ by shifting the indices $k$ steps. In other words, $b_{n} = a_{n+k}$

Suppose that $\lim a_n = L$, then

$$\forall\epsilon>0, \exists N \in \mathbb{N}: n\geq N\implies |a_n-L| < \epsilon$$

Hence, $n+k\geq N+k\implies |a_{n+k}-L| < \epsilon$. Set $N' = N + k$ and we have:
$$\forall\epsilon>0, \exists N' \in \mathbb{N}:n\geq N'\implies |b_{n}-L| < \epsilon$$

Hence, $b_n \to L$. Conversely, suppose that $b_n \to L$

$$\forall\epsilon>0, \exists N \in \mathbb{N}: n\geq N\implies |b_n-L| < \epsilon$$

Since this holds for $N$, it holds for the larger value $N+k$ as well. Hence

$$\forall\epsilon>0, \exists N \in \mathbb{N}: n\geq N +k\implies |b_n-L| < 
\epsilon$$
Therefore, we have 
$n-k\geq N \implies |b_{n-k}-L| < \epsilon$. But $n-k \geq 1$ and $b_{n-k}=a_n$. Hence

$$\forall\epsilon>0, \exists N \in \mathbb{N}: n\geq N\implies |a_n-L| < 
\epsilon$$

Proving that $a_n \to L$.

Comment: I think that the elements of $\{ b_{n}\}$ are $b_{1} = a_{k+1},b_{2} = a_{k+2}, ......, b_{n} = a_{k+n}$, .....

Comment: But how can I use this piece of information?

Comment: @Idonotknow   well, write the definition of convergence once for $\{a_n\}$ and another time for $\{b_n\}$. You should see that once one of the statements holds, the other one holds too by the kind of modification I told you about. The idea is that since $a_1,\cdots,a_k$ have been removed, if $N$ in the definition of convergence for $\{a_n\}$ happens to be smaller than $k$, you should choose a larger number that is bigger than $k$ that you don't run into trouble with $\{b_n\}$. Right?

Comment: I think it should be maximum of {N, k+1}.... right?

Comment: @Idonotknow  Yes, you're right. You could also use $N' = N+k$. That's another choice.

Comment: what about the proof that if {b_n} convergent then {a_{n} convergent?}

Comment: If $b_n$ converges, then you can find some $N$ that makes the definition work. Since $b_n = a_{n+k}$, then $N+k$ works for the convergence of $a_n$. Do you agree?

Comment: yes I agree but I am confused that N+k worked for both directions .... could you explain please?

Comment: @Idonotknow  Well, it shouldn't be surprising. Afterall, $b_n$ is obtained from $a_n$ by shifting the indices $k$ step. Isn't it so? That's why shifting indices works.

Comment: could you write the detailed answer for me please?

Comment: must they converge to the same number?

Comment: @Idonotknow  let me edit my answer. You're still confused.

Comment: @Idonotknow  check the answer again. Is it clear now?

Comment: what is the importance of saying that $n-k \geq 1$ and why we are sure from this?

Comment: @Idonotknow $n-k \geq N$ and $N$ is a natural number, hence $n-k \geq 1$. And it is important because if $n-k < 1$ then $b_{n-k}$ is meaningless. I think you now have everything you need to know.

Answer (score 1):

Use the definition of convergence. Suppose $\lim\limits_{n\to\infty} a_n = a$. For all $\epsilon > 0$ there exists some $N$ such that $d(a_n,a)<\epsilon$ for all $n\geq N$. Now, modify $N$ accordingly.

Comment: what is the importance of saying that $n-k \geq 1$ and why we are sure from this?

Answer (score 0):

$\{a_n\}_n$ converges to  $A$  iff for every $r>0$ the set $\{n:a_n\not \in [-r+A, r+A]\}$ is finite.

If we delete the first $k$ terms of  $\{a_n\}_n$ then we have a new series $\{b_n\}_n=\{a_{n+k}\}_n.$

For any $r>0$ we have $$\{n:b_n\not \in [-r+A,r+A]\} =$$ $$=\{n:a_{n+k}\not \in [-r+A,r+A]\}=$$ $$=\{n'>k :a_{n'}\not \in [-r+A,r+A]\}\subset$$ $$\subset \{n':a_{n'}\not\in [-r+A,r+A]\}.$$ This last set is finite.

Generalized: A sub-sequence of $\{a_n\}_n$   is $\{b_n\}=\{a_{f(n)}\}_n$ for some (any) strictly increasing $f:\Bbb N\to \Bbb N.$ If $\{a_n\}$ converges to $A$ then for any $r>0$ we have  $$\{n:b_n\not \in [-r+A,r+A]\}=$$ $$=\{f(n'):b_{f(n')}\not\in [-r+A,r+A]\}=$$ $$=\{n'': \exists n'\;(\;f(n')=n''\land a_{n''}\not \in  [-r+A,r+A]\;)\} \subset$$ $$\subset \{n'':a_{n''}\not \in [-r+A,r+A]\}$$ and this last set is finite.

In your Q, $\;f(n)=n+k.$